# Docker wait for web app to start (dependency)

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

Short question. I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:6.9.2

RUN apt-get update

RUN useradd --user-group --create-home --shell /bin/false app

ENV HOME=/home/app

RUN mkdir -p $HOME
RUN chown -R app:app $HOME

USER app
WORKDIR $HOME/

VOLUME ["/home/app/uploads"]

EXPOSE 5001

CMD [ "npm", "run", "test-integration" ]
```

and the corresponding docker-compose:
    version: '2.0'

```
services:
  komed-test-integration:
    image: borntraegermarc/komed-test-integration
    container_name: komed-test-integration
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - komed-app
      - komed-mongo
    volumes:
      - .:/home/app
    environment:
      - HOST_URL=komed-app
      - HOST_PORT=5001
      - MONGO_HOST=komed-mongo
      - MONGO_DATABASE=komed-health
```

I have the dependency to `komed-app` in my compose file and that works fine. But how do I wait for these integration tests to start until the web server (`komed-app`) is actually running? Tried with `CMD [ "./wait-for-it.sh", "komed-app-test:5001", "--", "npm", "run", "test-integration" ]` but didn't work. Always get the error `exited with code 127`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any error message with the error code? What's in wait-for-it.sh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is described in [Controlling startup order in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/).

You can either use [`depends-on`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends-on) or (better) [`vishnubob/wait-for-it`](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) (which you did).
127 is mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/issues/5#issuecomment-208497785), when the timeout fails.

[Docker node 6.9.2](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/6948057bbd9cc1469ca0e5e64d3bd5f000d4dc97/6.9/Dockerfile) depends on jessie, not Alpine, so it should not be affected by [issue 6](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/pull/6): so try and debug the script, by adding -x to the [first line](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/blob/master/wait-for-it.sh#L1)

```
 #!/usr/bin/env bash -x
```

You will see which [`exit $RESULT`](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/blob/master/wait-for-it.sh#L142) produced that 127 error code.

The [OP Marc Borni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3955332/marc-borni) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41324821/docker-wait-for-web-app-to-start-dependency/41327640?noredirect=1#comment69971098_41327640) the origin of the issue: windows file encoding for a unix script.
Sometimes, [using `dos2unix` directly in a `Dockerfile`](http://willi.am/blog/2016/08/11/docker-for-windows-dealing-with-windows-line-endings/) can help.

Comment: Problem was that I had windows file encoding. Thanks!

Comment: @MarcBorni Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.